# How to multiply an element of List<double[]> by a scalar

Tags: c#, linq

Having a `List<double[]>` with data

```
List<double[]> sqlResult = new List<double[]>();
sqlResult.Add(new double[] { 11, 21, 31 });
sqlResult.Add(new double[] { 12, 22, 32 });
sqlResult.Add(new double[] { 13, 23, 33 });
sqlResult.Add(new double[] { 14, 24, 34 });
```

How can I multiply the third element of each row by  `-1` so I would get

```
{ 11, 21, -31 }
{ 12, 22, -32 }
{ 13, 23, -33 }
{ 14, 24, -34 }
```

Do not know how to do it with LINQ

```
sqlResult= sqlResult.Select(item  =>  -item[2]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you avoid access by index, you won't get a exception if there are less than 3 elements within your List.

```
sqlResult = sqlResult.Select(x => x.Select((y, i) => i == 2 ? -y : y).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice solution as its independent of the Index access, +1

Answer (score 1):

`var result  = sqlResult.Select(x => new double[] { x[0], x[1], x[2] * -1}).ToList()`;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sqlResult.ForEach(y => y[2]= y[2] * -1);
```

Comment: By far the most intuitive of the lot.

Comment: @YannickMeeus OP was asking for a `Linq` approach

Comment: Correct but its not a `Linq` solution, this is a `ForEach` loop modifying the element accessed and would have index dependency like my solution, nonetheless intuitive approach +1